# EC2 + Apache + Miniconda + mod_wsgi import errors

Tags: python-3.x, apache, amazon-ec2, mod-wsgi, miniconda

I'm trying to get apache and mod_wsgi to work on an amazon ec2 instance, using a miniconda3 virtual environment and I am unable to get the WSGIDaemonProcess to correctly load the python venv modules (getting the 'encodings' module not found errors). I have run `mod_wsgi-express module-config` to get the proper path settings.

The relevant lines from my http.conf:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module "/home/ec2-user/miniconda3/envs/ebenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py36.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so"
WSGIPythonHome "/home/ec2-user/miniconda3/envs/ebenv"

WSGIDaemonProcess django python-home=/home/ec2-user/miniconda3/envs/ebenv python-path=/home/ec2-user/enerbits
WSGIProcessGroup django
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ec2-user/repo/website/wsgi.py
```

When I perform a `sudo strace httpd -X` I can see that it is trying to load files from a `/lib64` dir that doesn't exist in the venv. Here is the output:

```
stat("/home/ec2-user/miniconda3/envs/ebenv/lib64/python3.6", 0x7ffe873e1860) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/ec2-user/miniconda3/envs/ebenv/lib64", 0x7ffe873e1860) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/ec2-user/miniconda3/envs/ebenv", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/ec2-user/miniconda3/envs/ebenv/lib64/python3.6", 0x7ffe873e0ec0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/ec2-user/miniconda3/envs/ebenv/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload", 0x7ffe873e1860) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/ec2-user/miniconda3/envs/ebenv/lib64/python3.6", 0x7ffe873e1860) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/ec2-user/miniconda3/envs/ebenv/lib64", 0x7ffe873e1860) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/ec2-user/miniconda3/envs/ebenv", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/ec2-user/miniconda3/envs/ebenv/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload", 0x7ffe873e0ec0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I have tried reinstalling miniconda, mod_wsgi (both using pip and building from source) to no avail. I've searched around and found a few posts that detailed a solution to point the python-path to the site-packages dir or even moving libs into a different dir which seem like a dodgy option. The miniconda3 install is 64-bit.

To note, previously I had been using virtualenv to make a python env and it was working fine (I suppose because the `/lib64` dir is used) but I need to use conda for a pytorch installation. Any help is greatly appreciated. I am not particularly well versed in sysadmin stuff of this type so I am somewhat muddling my way through it all.

Comment: You sure that system mod_wsgi module isn't also being loaded into Apache before you try loading that which was installed using ``pip``.

Comment: I will check that and get back to you, but just want to provide an update: I've gotten things working by simply adding a symlink in the venv for `lib64 -> lib`. I don't like it, but it works.

Comment: As far as I can tell it isn't loading another mod_wsgi. `grep -r mod_wsgi /etc/httpd/` returns only the line I've included above from my http.conf file